# simple common table expression to flatten a tree

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Following is the table format that I have.
Table name :: USERS

```
userid reporttouserid
------ ------------
101    NULL
102    101
103    102
```

Now I need a query to list all the child user ids under 101 that is 102 and 103 both (103 is indirectly under 101 as its parent 102 is under 101)

I have seen the common table expression in postgresql but not being able to figure out how to go about it.

Comment: Please show what you tried, and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: what I have done so far is to select the direct child by joining with userid and pass that to a recursive function in java backend to find the subsequent users. I would prefer to do this in sql itself. I am not being able to understand how to write this kind of recursive query in sql. Thanks

Comment: If memory serves, the with recursive example in the PG docs has a query almost identical to the one you'll end up using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) covers this topic. See the examples given for recursive CTEs on that page.

Recursive CTEs can be a bit hard to grasp, but are very powerful once you use them. Read the documentation and experiment a little; you'll get it.

*(Please always mention your PostgreSQL version and **show desired output** in table-like form in your questions).*

Given demo data:

```
create table users (
  userid integer primary key,
  reporttouserid integer references users(userid)
);

insert into users(userid, reporttouserid) values (101,null), (102,101), (103,102);
```

*(please provide this in questions where possible, it's a pain to have to create it)*

you can recursively walk the graph with something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE flatusers(userid, reporttouserid, baseuserid) AS (
    SELECT userid, reporttouserid, userid AS baseuserid 
    FROM users WHERE reporttouserid IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u.userid, u.reporttouserid, f.baseuserid
    FROM flatusers f
    INNER JOIN users u ON f.userid = u.reporttouserid

)
SELECT * FROM flatusers;
```

producing output like:

```
 userid | reporttouserid | baseuserid 
--------+----------------+------------
    101 |                |        101
    102 |            101 |        101
    103 |            102 |        101
(3 rows)
```

I'm sure you can figure out where to go from there. Make sure you **understand** that recursive CTE before using it.

Be aware that PostgreSQL (9.4 or older at least) cannot (unfortunately) push quals down into CTE terms, even for non-recursive CTEs. If you add `WHERE baseuserid = 101` to your query, the query will still generate the *entire* flattened table, then throw most of it away. If you want to do this recursive operation for just *one* baseuserid, you must add the appropriate `WHERE` clause term after `WHERE reporttouserid IS NULL` in the static union part of the recursive CTE term.