# Display child and parent relationship (if any) in a same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
| id |parent|name|
| 1  | NULL |  E |
| 2  | NULL |  B |
| 3  | 5    |  U |
| 4  | 5    |  X |
| 5  | NULL |  C |
| 6  | NULL |  A |
```

I would like the list, ordered by parent's name, of all ID whether they have a parent or not:

```
| id |parent|name|has_child|
| 6  | NULL |  A |    0    |
| 2  | NULL |  B |    0    |
| 5  | NULL |  C |    1    |
| 3  | 5    |  U |    0    |
| 4  | 5    |  X |    0    |
| 1  | NULL |  E |    0    |
```

Is it possible?

I have tried many things but never get the proper answer, and I don't really know how to add the 'has_child' column

```
SELECT
  t1.parent,
  t2.name
FROM tablename AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MIN(id) AS id, parent
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY parent
) AS t22 ON t22.id = t1.id AND t1.parent = t22.parent
INNER JOIN tablename AS t2 ON t1.parent = t2.id;
```

Comment: if you want `has_children` column - then just add it. You might keep it updates using `SQL Triggers`, providing the engine you selected for the table supports those. After every row is inserted/updated/deleted - recalculate of children count for the affected 1 or 2 parent rows.

Comment: My crystall ball engaged, i am staring deep inside and hereby DECLARE: what the topic starter actually wants is a RECURSIVE query that FLATTENS the tree into a list, where each parent is immediately followed by his children (if any), and each of those children is immediately followed by their children (parent's grand children), and so forth. The query typically made by RECURSIVE CTE, by i am not sure if My SQL has those. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905366 and http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/community/ppts/fbcon11/FBTrees2011.pdf for examples

Comment: Seems to be dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524275/flatten-a-tree-in-mysql

Comment: Check these tutorials: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-recursive-cte/ and especially check **employees example** at https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3634

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a self join -- because you want the name of the parent and not the id -- and `coalesce()` for ordering:

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from t tc where tc.parent = t.id)
             then 1 else 0
        end)
from t left join
     t tp
     on t.parent = tp.id
order by coalesce(tp.name, t.name),   -- group rows by the parent, if any
         (tp.name is null) desc,      -- put parent first
         t.name;                      -- order by children
```

Comment: There is no need for one more the same sub-select, is there? just check for `tp.id is null` in your `case`

Comment: also, why `coalesce(tp.name, t.name)` ? you just prohibit using of indexes for sorting doing that way.

Comment: Thank you! It looks good, but name C (parent) is displayed *after* U and X (children)

Comment: @Jibeji if you want "order by name" then name C does go before the U and X, as Latin alphabet order shows. If you want to unroll the tree by parent-child relation, it is not "ordering by name" but a very different thing. Google for unrolling or expanding or flattening trees in MySQL. Usually it is done by a recursive Common Table Expression or by a recursive Stored Procedure if CTE is not supported but SP is.

Comment: @Jibeji . . . I fixed the order by so the parent is first.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  with ASC instead of DESC this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I would use a self join here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.id,
    t1.parent,
    t1.name,
    1 - ISNULL(t2.id) has_child
FROM tablename t1
LEFT JOIN tablename t2
    ON t1.id = t2.parent
ORDER BY
    t1.id;
```

The join condition used here, which matches a given record as a parent to one or more children, is that the current `id` is also the `parent` of some other record(s).  Note that we need `SELECT DISTINCT` here, because a given parent might match to more than one child record.

Comment: Thanks but the order of name is not respected

Answer (score 2):

I hope that you find this answer a little bit useful. The subquery gets the distinct id of parents and excludes the blanked fills.

```
SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN id IN (SELECT DISTINCT parent
                        FROM tablename
                        WHERE parent IS NOT NULL)
            THEN '1' ELSE '0'
            END AS has_child
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.parent, t1.name, MAX(t2.parent is not null) has_child
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.parent, t1.name
```

Comment: Thanks but the order of name is not respected

Comment: @Jibeji Nothing prevents to add proper ORDER BY.